# How to prefer ipv4 for google-auth-library requests in nodejs on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, ipv6, google-api-nodejs-client

As of later versions of nodejs, `ipv6 DNS` resolution is preferred. In previous machines, I had simply disabled `ipv6` for outgoing requests, but here it isn't possible because `fetch()` in node would fail without it.

However, some specific Google endpoints, namely `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs`

Require `ipv4` resolution, which is requested internally by `OAuth2Client` in `google-auth-library` (via **Axios**).
The response I get from the request using `ipv6` is:

```
Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/oauth2/v1/certs</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

403: Forbidden
```

So what solutions are there to force only these requests to prefer `ipv4`?

Answer (score 0):

Node provides an option to prefer IPv4 Resolution:

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--dns-result-order=ipv4first`

This will of course apply to all requests. If you really need to resolve other requests with IPv6 you could provide a custom agent/dispatcher to the specific request(s).

Here's an example using `undici` but you may be able to use `https.Agent` as well:

```
import { Agent } from 'undici';

await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs', {
  dispatcher: new Agent({
    connect: {
      lookup: (hostname, options, callback) => {
        return dns.resolve4(hostname, options, callback);
      },
    },
  }),
});
```